# Creating a HttpModule of generic type

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, httpmodule

I'm trying to write a simple IHttpModule that (in the case of this example) records each page a logged-in user is hitting. I'm trying to make it generic across several Web apps so that it can be used with several different types of user objects.

I have an interface `ILogUser` that has one property:

```
public interface ILogUser
{
  public string LoggingRef { get;}
}
```

I have several different user objects across various Web apps that inherit from this interface:

```
public class StaffMember : ILogUser
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  // many more properties
  public string LoggingRef { get { return Name; }}
}

public class ExtranetUser : ILogUser
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Email { get; set; }
  // many more properties
  public string LoggingRef { get { return Email; }}
}
```

Etc.

My HttpModule is coded as follows:

```
public class LogVisitModule<T> : IHttpModule where T : ILogUser
{
  private readonly ILog log;

  public LogVisitModule()
  {
    log = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
  }

  public void Init(HttpApplication app)
  {
    app.PostAcquireRequestState += new EventHandler(this.PostAcquireRequestState);
  }

  private void PostAcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    HttpApplication app = (HttpApplication)sender;
    HttpContext context = app.Context;

    if (context.Session != null && context.Session["CurrentUser"] != null)
    {
      var user = (T)context.Session["CurrentUser"];
      log.Info($"User {user.LoggingRef} has accessed {context.Request.FilePath}");
    }
  }

  public void Dispose() { }
}
```

And I dynamically load the module in my Global.asax with the appropriate assembly attribute and method call:

`[assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(WebPortal.MvcApplication), "Start")]`

```
public static void Start()
{
  HttpApplication.RegisterModule(typeof(LogVisitModule<StaffMember>));
}
```

When I boot up my Web app I get the Server Error:

> Could not load type 'WebPortal.Modules.LogVisitModule'.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Could not load type
>   'WebPortal.Modules.LogVisitModule'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

ANY help would be appreciated! I hope what I'm trying to do makes sense? I don't even know if what I'm doing is possible. I've Googled dynamically loading HttpModules with generic types but haven't found a whole lot.

Comment: Is it possible to just operate on `object`s?

Comment: This line in the constructor bugs me `MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType`, why not a simple `GetType()` ?

Comment: @CSharpie - bad copy & paste :) Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Out of curiosity, if you remove the generics from the LogVisitModule, it loads and runs as expected?

Comment: @Alex - yes, it runs perfectly without the generics.

Comment: In that case, @BarryGallagher, the next thing to try is using `LogVisitModule<T>` as a base class, and make subclasses whose only purpose is to set the value of `T`, e.g. `public class StaffMemberLogVisitModule : LogVisitModule<StaffMember> {}` and try registering that one.

Comment: Unfortunately that throws the exact same error @Alex

Comment: Oh well. Worth a try, @BarryGallagher. :)